# .NET Membership.GetUser() null in ie9 and safari when embedded in iframe

Tags: c#, .net, iframe, membership

Ok, I'm stumped.  Here's the scenario: 
I have a .net 4.0 mvc3 app (razor) embedded in an iframe on a remote site. I have a standard Membership provider for security and everything works fine as long as I use Chrome or Firefox.    However when I use ie9 (both in and out of compatibility mode) and safari (only tried 5.1.4) I get a System.NullReferenceException when trying to access Membership.GetUser() in another controller after logging in.

So I login successfully in my AccountController and redirect to my TravelController here:

```
public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (MembershipService.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                FormsService.SignIn(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                log.Debug("User: " + model.UserName + " logged in."); 
                return RedirectToAction("Travel", "Travel");
            }
        }
    }
    catch(....
```

Now the app redirects to the TravelController which does the following:

```
public ActionResult Travel()
{
    try
    {
        string userName = Membership.GetUser().UserName;
        ... code ...
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

So this all works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but when I try to run the same code using ie or safari the Membership object is null.

I have a feeling it is somehow related to the iframe, but I'm second guessing everything now.  If I run it outside of iframe; meaning I call the url directly it runs in all browsers (that I've tried).

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at p3p headers?

Answer (score 2):

Authentication is based on cookies. Internet Explorer doesn't allow 3rd party sites in an iframe to use cookies if they don't provide a machine readable privacy policy. See http://www.softwareprojects.com/resources/programming/t-how-to-get-internet-explorer-to-use-cookies-inside-1612.html and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P3P for details.

So you should add an appropriate header to the site(s) and it should work fine.

Hope that helps.